# Directly connected HP server and CX4 with fibre

Tags: emc

I have direcly connected (with fibre) a HP ProLiant BL460c G7 with a EMC CX4. I installed VMWare Esxi 5.0. The problem is that cx4 cannot connect to the blade. It seems that there is no connectivity problem, because the server can be connected to fibre switch with other equipment (EVA 4000) and also cx4 is already atteched to one same server.

The problem seems to exist somewhere between the cx4 and esxi when they are direclty attached.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on CX4s but on lots of other arrays the host ports have the ability to be in either 'loop' or 'switch' mode - some have auto-sensing. 'Loop' mode is the one you'd use for direct connection, i.e. without a switch in between. See if the CX4 has this option on the port/s you've connected the server to. There's no equivalent setting on the server by the way, you need to do this on the array's ports.

As an example on your EVA 4400 if you look in either Command View or via the web interface you can look at the host ports and see that they'll be set to 'Loop' mode (or similar, I can't recall the exact term) when directly connected.

Either way look at your array's host ports, hopefully there'll be a very small selection of configuration options, one of them will work for direct connection.